# Check sort order value OpenCart in foreach

Tags: php, menu, module, opencart

I'm making a custom menu module for information pages in OpenCart and want to exclude certain pages from the menu. I was hoping to use the "Sort Order" value to exclude pages from the menu.

For example: pages with any sort order number, except number 999, will be included in the menu, but all pages with the sort order number 999 will be skipped.

My issue is checking the sort order value. I can't figure out how to get this value.
I searched on all terms I can think of, but all I find are lots of pages/posts about setting the sort-by-order.

Comment: If this is a programming question please share the code you've tried so we can help you debug it.  If this is a request for general Opencart support try the opencart.com community forums.

Comment: I suppose this would be a general OpenCart question. I did post the question in the OpenCart forum, but approval took quite some time, therefor I asked here. A little inpatient I guess...